# validation without strongly typed views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How to perform validation on server side, if I am not creating strongly typed views. Just plain views with

```
<input id="in1" name="in1" value="" />
<input id="in2" name="in2" value="" />
<input id="in3" name="in3" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on what framework you are using for validation on your server side. Data Annotations work by decorating your view model classes with validation attributes. If you don't use view models (which would be **very bad** design) you could always perform the validation manually (which would be **very bad** design):

```
// NEVER WRITE CODE LIKE THIS! USE VIEW MODELS
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string int1, string int2, string int3)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(int1))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("int1", "int1 is required");
    }
    ....
}
```